# Using Mono<T> in Spring to populate a Cloud Firestore entity

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-firestore, spring-data, spring-reactive

I am using [`spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/spring-cloud-gcp.html#_cloud_firestore) for accessing [Google Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) in my Java Spring application.

Currently, my entity looks like this:

```
public class Subscription {

    public String userId;
    public String companyId;

    // other properties

}
```

However, I obtain the `userId` and `companyId` via a [`reactor.core.publisher.Mono`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) in [`org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.html).

How can I persist both properties which are nested inside `Mono`s without resorting to [`Mono#block`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--)?

Comment: What do you mean by `persist both properties`? Why do you want to avoid `Mono#block`?

Comment: @Juancki By using `Mono#block` I would throw "away all the benefits of the Reactive Streams" according to the Spring documentation: https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/13/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-ii-writing-some-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using [`Mono#zipWith`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWith-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) to combine both `Mono`s. Then I am creating the entity inside `Mono#flatMap`.

```
service.getCompanyId()
   .zipWith(service.getUserId())
   .flatMap(objects -> createEntity(objects.getT1(), objects.getT2()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following the tutorial in the [Google codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-datastore/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_datastore_mode) you can find that Firestore can be in Datastore mode which makes the previous tutorial suitable for you.